# Is Talut (Saul) a prophet in Islam?

Tags: prophets, bani-israel

The Qur'an says that Saul was sent to Israel as a king. But was he just the king and commander or also a prophet??

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear textual evidence that Saul was a prophet. It is claimed that David  عليه السلام  was the first person who was both the King and the Prophet of Bani Israel.

Some have argued that Saul could be a prophet and among the evidence they cite is:

> فلما فصل طالوت بالجنود قال إن الله مبتليكم بنهر
>
> And when Saul went forth with the soldiers, he said, "Indeed, Allah will be testing you with a river ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:249](https://quran.com/2/249?translations=20)</sup>

This suggests that he received revelation. Although it is also possible that the revelation actually occurred to Samuel  عليه السلام  who informed Saul.

> وقال لهم نبيهم إن آية ملكه أن يأتيكم التابوت فيه سكينة من ربكم وبقية مما ترك آل موسى وآل هارون تحمله الملائكة إن في ذلك لآية لكم إن كنتم مؤمنين
>
> And their prophet said to them, "Indeed, a sign of his kingship is that the chest will come to you in which is assurance from your Lord and a remnant of what the family of Moses and the family of Aaron had left, carried by the angels. Indeed in that is a sign for you, if you are believers."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:248](https://quran.com/2/248?translations=20)</sup>

This sign could be taken as a miracle which accompanies a prophet in response to a challenge and as evidence. However it could also be a *karaamah* which can occur at the hand of a *wali*, or it could be a miracle of prophet Samuel  عليه السلام .

**References:**

> جمع الله لداود بين الملك والنبوة ولم يكن من قبل بل كان الملك في سبط والنبوة في سبط
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://shamela.ws/book/41/338)</sup>
>
> لم يجتمعوا قبل داود على ملك والحكمة أي النبوة
>
> <sup>— [Tafseer al-Baydaawi](https://shamela.ws/book/23588/144)</sup>

> من الناس من قال: إن طالوت كان نبيا، لأنه تعالى أظهر المعجزة على يده وكل من كان كذلك كان نبيا، ولا يقال: إن هذا كان من كرامات الأولياء، لأن الفرق بين الكرامة والمعجزة أن الكرامة لا تكون على سبيل التحدي، وهذا كان على سبيل التحدي، فوجب أن لا يكون من جنس الكرامات.والجواب: لا يبعد أن يكون ذلك معجزة لنبي ذلك الزمان، ومع كونه معجزة له فإنه كان آية قاطعة في ثبوت ملكه.
>
> <sup>— [Tafseer al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/1126#p6)</sup>
>
> استدل من قال إن طالوت كان نبيا بقوله:" إن الله مبتليكم" وأن الله أوحى إليه بذلك وألهمه، وجعل الإلهام ابتلاء من الله لهم. ومن قال لم يكن نبيا قال: أخبره نبيهم شمويل بالوحي حين أخبر طالوت قومه بهذا، وإنما وقع هذا الابتلاء ليتميز الصادق من الكاذب
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/1159#p1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The children of Israel asked the Prophet of their time to set up a kingdom for them to fight in the way of God. [20] The Prophet, by divine command, chose Talut as king.
(20). Surah Al-Baqarah, verse 246